# angular material mat-error not showing when implementing MatFormFieldControl and ControlValueAccessor

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a custom control that implements both MatFormFieldControl and ControlValueAccessor, and although the form is invalid and has error I cannot get mat-error to display.

Main formgroup:

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <mat-form-field>
    <app-test-input formControlName="testControl"></app-test-input>
    <mat-hint>test</mat-hint>
    <mat-error *ngIf="formGroup.get('testControl').hasError('required')">
      required
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
  <button (click)="submit()">Submit</button>
</form>
<p *ngIf="formGroup">
  {{formGroup.value | json}} {{
  formGroup.get('testControl').hasError('required') }}
</p>
```

custom control:

```
<div [formGroup]="FormGrp">
  <input formControlName="data" (input)="input()" />
</div>
```

Here is a stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tzgaxz-upn2yn

I would expect clicking the submit button to show the error, but I cannot figure out where I am going wrong. The error only appears when blurring the input.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for start in your stackblitz you're not importing `MatFormFieldModule` which is required for `mat-error` to work properly (not rly, but I will keep it simple). Next problem is that `mat-form-field` is looking for direct input descendant with `matInput` directive. I am assuming you're trying to customize input visuals to your liking. I don't think using material design that way is correct approach. Just create your own component with similar approach to error handling as Angular Material.

I've provided corrected version to your stackblitz as suggested in Angular Material documentation. As you see it's working properly.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tzgaxz-kmbtka?file=app/form-field-overview-example.html

In theory you can fight with that behavior, however I do not advice for that.

PS. Your problem is not related to the "error" state of ReactiveFormInput, but to `mat-form-field` controling visibility of `mat-error` element from within it's own styles/component.

Comment: I need to keep the component though, you removed it and replaced it with input directly.

Comment: @Paul Yes, I had to do that. I don't know why you need to keep component, but if you do, I suggest creating your own wrapper instead of using material one. As I said in my response `mat-form-field` requires "matInput" as a direct child, because it needs to hook into MatFormFieldControl to check for input events like "focus". A lot of things from `mat-form-field` depends on direct input child with `matInput` directive. Just get rid of material and create your own `error` component and `input-wrapper` :) No need to fight with library.

Comment: Sorry, but I am looking to making it work with a custom control per my example. Thank you for looking at it.